# How can i save a song from my app in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i am unable to download the song from internet but i can listen the song but i want to my app to perform as, when i am clicking the play button it should download that song too.

```
playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if(web[position] == web[0]){

        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mPlayer.seekTo(0);

        }      
        else{   
            Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse("http://sound21.mp3slash.net/320/indian/bajrangibhaijaan/01%20-%20Selfie%20Le%20Le%20Re%20-%20Bajrangi%20Bhaijaan%20[Songspk.LINK].mp3");

        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), myUri1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mPlayer.start();
        playbtn.setText("Pause");
    }
```

Comment: So, what's the error ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427533/downloading-an-mp3-file-from-server-in-android

Comment: @JagadeshSeeram sir how can i use this i have to make a separate class and then how can i used it for every different song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean when you click button , start playing and downloading?
Use DownloadManager to download the audio file.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: yes but i could get it how to use download Manager i used it but it isn't working.