# How can I download a mp3 file on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How can I download a .mp3 file from a URL in the Android download directory?
Using [OutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream) and [InputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream) apparently doesn't work anymore. Here's what I've tried:

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private final String videoUrl;

    public DownloadFile(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(videoUrl);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            String test = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/test.mp3";
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(test);

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            output.write(data);

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This can download the file, but when trying to play it I receive a error message [saying that I can't play this type of audio file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJzdV.png).

Also, the code above was get from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427533/downloading-an-mp3-file-from-server-in-android).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are not reading from the inputstream. There should be a loop that does.

Comment: If I want to play a mp3 file and the player doesn't recognize or can't play a mp3 file, I'm assuming that I didn't download a mp3 file - or it's a player problem, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know the DownloadManager Class From Android (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager)

```
 
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("your url here"));
request.setDescription("Downloading");
request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
request.setTitle("File :");
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();         
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "audio.mp3");
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this exactly code but the player also doesn't play the audio. I'm not sure if I'm not downloading a MP3 file or if that's a player problem.